# Уделение внимания

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать "уделение внимания" или "обращение внимания" (на что-либо)? Оба варианта режут слух. Может, есть какая-то альтернатива?

Comment: Контекст:

Учитывая, что лето — сезон "горящих" туров и жарких отпусков, а значит, и обращения особого внимания на размер получаемой заработной платы, тему подобрать было несложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я считаю, *"уделение внимания"* - это проявление симпатии, заинтересованности, а *"обращение внимания"* - это временное концентрирование внимания на чем-то определенном.
Синонимичные фразы надо искать, зная, какой смысл вы вкладываете.

Answer (score 3):

Грамматически все правильно. Но стилистически как-то искусственно звучит. Глагол и отглагольное существительное не всегда взаимозаменяемы.
Если исходить из приведенного контекста, то лучше было бы, на мой взгляд, сказать так: *"Учитывая, что лето — сезон "горящих" туров и жарких отпусков, а значит, и особого внимания к размеру получаемой заработной платы, тему подобрать было несложно".*

Answer (score 2):

Альтернатива тут только одна. Постарайтесь не говорить *красиво*. Зачем вообще понадобилось обозначать подобное действие существительным?
Если действиnельно думаете, что никак без этого, то давайте контекст, разберемся.
Кстати, из двух зол я бы предпочел первое, уделение. "Обращение внимания" как-то совсем не звучит.

Comment: Если очень нужно существительное, есть еще вариант - оказание внимания.

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой при переводе фразы "paing special attention"... Спасибо за вариант "акцентирование внимания"! А вообще, фраза, приведенная в начале ("Учитывая, что лето — сезон "горящих" туров и жарких отпусков, а значит, и обращения особого внимания..."), неграмотна в целом, так как из нее вытекает, что лето - это сезон жарких отпусков? а также СЕЗОН обращения внимания. Правильнее было бы "Учитывая, что лето — сезон "горящих" туров и жарких отпусков, когда особое внимание уделяется..." и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Акцентирование внимания

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, будет лучше и более естественно употребить *уделить внимание* и/или *обратить внимание*. Инфинитив (*уделить*) и существительное (*уделение*) очень близки по синтаксическим функциям.

Давайте контекст в вопросе -- тогда будут более конкретные ответы.